# Не обновляется ListView и ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такое задание:

реализация MVC на WPF...Может показаться странным, ибо есть немного code behind, да и для WPF не очень то и подходит данный паттерн, но не в этом проблема и суть :) Подключение к SQL базе, там простенькая таблица(ID, Фамилия, Имя)

Программа простая до нельзя - listView со списком людей и кнопка "добавить".

Пытался сделать по примеру, что нашел в интернетах. 
***По факту***, у меня задание сделано, ***НО*** при добавлении нового студента в ListView ничего не отображается, только после перезапуска программы, добавленные студенты появляются в списке.

Может в данном случае поможет PropertyChanged - но не могу понять, как его сюда впихнуть.

Есть DataService

```
public interface IDataService<T> where T : class
{
    ObservableCollection<T> GetStudents();
}

public class DataService<T> : IDataService<T> where T : class 
{
    private readonly TheThirdMVCEntities _entities; //База данных SQL

    public DataService()
    {
        _entities = new TheThirdMVCEntities();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<T> GetStudents() //список студентов
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<T>(_entities.Set<T>());
    }
}
```

StudentModel

```
    public interface IStudentsModel<T> where T : class
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> Students { get; set; }
        void AddStudent(T entity);
        void RemoveStudent(T entity);
    }

    public class StudentsModel<T> : IStudentsModel<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly TheThirdMVCEntities _entities;

        public ObservableCollection<T> Students { get; set; }

        public StudentsModel()
        {
            Students = new DataService<T>().GetStudents();
            _entities = new TheThirdMVCEntities();
        }

        public void AddStudent(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void RemoveStudent(T entity) //удаление по макс ID, пусть пока остается так :)
        {
            var maxId = (_entities.Students.Select(x => (int?) x.StudentID).Max() ?? 0);
            _entities.Set<Student>().Remove((from del in _entities.Students where del.StudentID == maxId select del).First());

            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

StudentController

```
public interface IStudentsController<T> where T : class
{
    void AddStudent(T entity);
    void RemoveStudent(T entity);
}

public class StudentsController<T> : IStudentsController<T> where T : class
{
    public readonly IStudentsModel<T> Model;

    public StudentsController()
    {
        Model = new StudentsModel<T>();
    }

    public void AddStudent(T entity)
    {
        Model.AddStudent(entity);
    }

    public void RemoveStudent(T entity)
    {
        Model.RemoveStudent(entity);
    }
}
```

Code behind

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    private readonly IStudentsModel<Student> _model;
    private readonly IStudentsController<Student> _controller
        = null;

    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; } 

    public Student SelectedStudent { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _controller = new StudentsController<Student>();
        _model = new StudentsModel<Student>();

        listView.ItemsSource = _model.Students;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _controller.AddStudent(new Student { FirtsName = "Иванов", LastName = "Иван" });
    }

    private void remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _controller.RemoveStudent(SelectedStudent);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow"
    FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=listView}">
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listView"
              SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirtsName}" Header="FirstName" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Header="LastName" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="button"
            Click="button_Click"
            Content="Добавить" />
    <Button x:Name="remove"
            Click="remove_Click"
            Content="Удалить" />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну а с чего у Вас будет что-то обновляться, когда Вы один раз инициализируете `ObservableCollection`, а потом в ней ничего не меняете? Хотите изменений? Тогда везде, где Вы изменяете коллекцию в базе, меняйте также и `ObservableCollection`. К примеру, `AddStudent` могу бы выглядеть так:

```
public void AddStudent(T entity)
{
    _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    _entities.SaveChanges();
    Students.Add(entity);
}
```

Comment: Примерно нашел решение проблемы, у меня контроллер и модель в данной задаче по сути одно и тоже. Сделал, как сказал ixSci и в code behind: _model.AddStudent(new Student { FirtsName = "Иванов", LastName = "Иван" });